# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-multidex

I'm working on an android app using android studio for school and I'm trying to use Jersey client to connect the app with my web services.  I'm getting the following error when I attempt to add the jars required for Jersey client and compile the project.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

From searching around for a solution to this problem it seems to me it is occurring because I am exceeding a 65k limit on methods by adding the jars.  I've also seen that this can be fixed by using multidex support which I have tried to implement but the error remains when I compile the gradle.

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.williamj.hertz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LISCENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LISCENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/liscense.txt'
    }
    dexOptions{
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

And here is a portion of my AndroidManifest where I have added multidex support

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

I'm assuming that I'm just not implementing multidex support correctly.  Any help in fixing this error would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have your Application override attachBaseContext:

```
@Override

protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

link: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

2nd methode:
I also noticed that you are including all Google play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them. For information on how to do this, see: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project